# Normal distribution: mean value in a given area under the curve

Tags: normal-distribution

Given a standard normal distribution curve of mean 0 and standard deviation 1. Is there a way that we can calculate the mean value of the $x$ coordinate in a given area under the curve?
For example, we know that approximately 34.1% of the area is from 0 to 1. Since the probability is not uniformly distributed from 0 to 1, the mean value from 0 to 1 is not 0.5. Then what is it?
Is there a general formula to find this mean for any range of value, for example from 1 to 2?
Thanks much.
Update:

1. By curve I meant the probability density function.
2. I changed weighted value to mean value, which I believe it is better term term. For example, the mean value between -1 and 1 is 0 since the curve is symmetrical via x = 0 but how about the mean value between 1 and 2?
3. No, I'm not trying to find the area under the curve but I suspect it will be related.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "weighted average value of a given area under the curve"? By curve, do you mean the probability density function? Are you trying to find the area under the probability density function over a given range? For that you'd need the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function

Comment: Hi Matthias. Thanks for asking. I have clarified my question above. Mean value, I believe, is a better word.

Comment: Much clearer! Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same question has been asked and answered in [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/343828/expected-value-of-x-which-follows-a-normal-distribution-between-a-certain-int).

For the record, the solution for $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ has a delightfully simple formula
$$
\mathbb{E}(X \vert a\leq X \leq b) = \mu + \sigma \frac{\phi(\alpha) - \phi(\beta)}{\Phi(\beta) - \Phi(\alpha)}
$$
where $\alpha=(a-\mu)/\sigma$ and $\beta=(b-\mu)/\sigma$.

Plugging in $\mu=0$, $\sigma=1$, and $a=0$, $b=1$ we get
$$
\frac{\phi(0)-\phi(1)}{\Phi(1)-\Phi(0)} \approx 0.459862,
$$
and numerical approximation by rejection sampling gives a similar result.

Comment: Hi Jukka, thanks a lot for your answer. I did try to find an answer first but couldn't, probably because of my search keywords. Thank you!

Comment: I think I searched for *normal distribution "conditional mean in interval"*. It helps to recognize that the quantity you want is a conditional mean (or conditional expectation).

Comment: Thanks, Jukka, for being incredibly helpful!